# Get Controller name inside RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes()

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

Everybody knows those statements inside the static `RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes()` method:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "Teasers",
    "Teasers/{action}/{id}",
    new { controller = "Teasers", action = "Index", id = 0 }
    );
```

But that's not very type-safe. A hacky alternative would be:

```
var teasers = nameof(TeasersController).Replace("Controller", "");
routes.MapRoute(
    teasers,
    teasers + "/{action}/{id}",
    new {controller = teasers, action = "Index", id = 0}
);
```

Is there something elegant out there?

Comment: Search the internets

Comment: @Luke I did. Google as well as all suggestions Stackoverflow announced during my key strokes.

Comment: There's one for ASP.NET MVC Core >> https://github.com/ivaylokenov/AspNet.Mvc.TypedRouting  of course you need to be developing in Core and not the original one

Comment: @Luke Thanks. That's a nice tool. I'll consider it when we upgrade to ASP.NET MVC Core.

Comment: Looks like the same guy that developed that didn't bother developing it for original ASP.NET MVC, but felt compelled to with the Core version.  I wonder why that was...

Comment: Is it not possible to use Attribute Based Routing?